# flutter is not recognised from project directory

Tags: windows, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, flutter

Able to run flutter commands from src/flutter/bin. But if I am in my project directory or any other one,  'flutter' is not recognised. But there are some commands that should be run within the project like pub upgrate, pub outdated and etc. There is a similar question here ['flutter' command is not working in Root Directory of Project. [Windows]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55668378/flutter-command-is-not-working-in-root-directory-of-project-windows) but couldn't find an answer. Will be very grateful for help
[image]

[image]

Comment: This link should help
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path

Comment: Please follow this steps to update your path so that you can run flutter command in yout terminal: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Comment: Found that dart.exe is missing in the list                                                 c:\>where.exe flutter dart
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat
C:\src\flutter\bin\dart
C:\src\flutter\bin\dart.bat       Probably it's system antivirus that deleted it.Turned off antivirus.Will try to install dart sdk separately. If it doesn't work will reinstall Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me.

1. Turn off antivirus.
2. Reinstall Flutter SDK and Android Studio.
3. After following all instructions and installing plugins( https://medium.com/d6-digital/installing-the-flutter-in-windows-803f3cd1fa4c), go to File->Settings->Appearance-> Android SDK->SDK tools->enable Google USB Driver.

4.Then install Java SDK. You can find the link here(https://www.edureka.co/community/74624/how-to-install-java-in-windows-system?show=74624#q74624).

5.Add path to Java/bin to your variables.

Now it works from any directory

[image]